# Изображения в Angular2

Tags: изображения, angular2

Указываю изображения в html файле, и при выводе в продакшн они не отображаются. При запуске ng serve всё работает.
Изображения которые в css файле загружаются нормально всегда.
В чём проблема?

Comment: <base href="/"> менял, не решило проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Путь к файлам в html надо писать начиная с assets/ , не нужно писать ../../